# Can I say "it barely can not to be noticed, that "?

Tags: word-usage

Can I say:

it **barely can not to be noticed**, that **there are already** a sufficient number of ...

?

Comment: That's not grammatical.  It would help if we knew exactly what you were trying to say.

Comment: Unless we know what you *want* to say, we can't correct your text. I suspect you want to say something like *It can hardly go unnoticed that…* .

Comment: @choster, thank you. it is exactly what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

"It's barely noticeable that a sufficient number of..."

Avoiding words like "it" and "there" brings clarity to writing so perhaps your sentence is better structured like the one below.

"A sufficient number of ... were barely noticeable."

Answer (score 1):

Since barely, hardly, and scarcely already have negative force, it is redundant to use another negative in the same clause: he had barely had (not he hadn't barely had) time to think; there was scarcely any (not scarcely no)bread left

Comment: Not just redundant but confusing. Double negatives are hard to interpret; especially _barely_. If asked what _I have barely $500 in the bank_ means, a large group of English speakers will say I have a little bit more than  $500,  another large group will say I have a little less than  $500, and another group will say it's one or the other, but close to $500. _Barely_ is not a simple word.